# Time complexity question: why is it O(n log n)?

Tags: python, time-complexity

Can someone explain why this is `O(n log n)` and not `O(n^2)`? I had the idea that the `if` statement is `n` times and the `else` is `log n` so you pick the worst case between the two in this case is `O(n)` so multiply it with the outer loop `O(n)` making it `O(n^2)` but apparently is `O(n log n)` and I am not seeing how.

```py
for i in range( len(nums_lst)):
  if i < 10:
      for k in range( len(nums_lst)):
          print(nums_lst[0])
  else:
      j = 1
      while j < len(nums_lst):
          print(nums_lst[0])
          j *= 2
```

Comment: The worst case for O(n\*n) occurs when n=10; but this is negligible compared to say n=100000, when the complexity is O(n\*logn).

Comment: We only consider the term that contributes the most when calculating time complexity. As n approaches infinity, the contribution of the O(n^2) part approaches 0 (relative to the O(n log n) part).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to see what's going on if you rewrite it this way, which is equivalent when *n* ≥ 10:

```py
for i in range(10):
    for k in range(len(nums_lst)):
        print(nums_lst[0])

for i in range(10, len(nums_lst)):
    j = 1
    while j < len(nums_lst):
        print(nums_lst[0])
        j *= 2
```

The number of steps is 10*n* + (*n* − 10) log *n*.

Answer (score 0):

For a large value of n, the `if:` condition will be neglected.
Inside `else:`, while loop continues to run for -

> j = 1 and j = 2 and j = 4 and ... and j = 2^m where 2^m <= n

> So the total number of loops is m+1. And m = log n

Now the time complexity is `O(n * log n)`

```py
for i in range( len(nums_lst)):  # Time complexity O(n)
  if i < 10:
      ...
  else:
      j = 1
      while j < len(nums_lst):  # Time complexity O(logn)
          print(nums_lst[0])
          j *= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Big-O time complexity is an *asymptotic* measure of how an algorithm scales. It is concerned with how the algorithm scales as `n` approaches infinity, rather than for specific values of `n`.

When `nums_list` contains fewer than ten items, the complexity is O(n^2) but this is a negligible sample as `nums_list` scales in size.

The *much* larger sample will be represented by the else branch where `j` approaches `len(nums_list)` exponentially. Thus the complexity of the inner loop is O(log n).

Consequently, multiplying the two, we get O(n*log n).

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotic notations are always the measure of performance for larger inputs.
so if you are going to calculate Time Complexity go for Big-O (i.e) Worst case .

Since i< 10 is small we can neglect and take else part whose time complexity is O(log n to the base 2) and Outer for loop have T.C of O(n).

Hence O(n log n).

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm will be O(nlog(n)) because the chances of the execution of if block is very low because in the most cases the list will have more than 10 elements. Only in few worse cases the list will have less than 10 elements and the time complexity will be O(n^2). So, overall the algorithm will have a time complexity of O(nlog(n)).